# Update an Account in AMPscript (cloud page)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sales-cloud

I'm trying to update an account using AMPscript with the function `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject`. But I have just `personContactId` to achieve that.

```
SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
  "Account", @PersonContactId, ...)
```

That code is returning error 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer would be "you'll need to get hold of the accountId". A suboptimal approach would be to modify your code to first get the accountId using the [RetrieveSalesforceObjects()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) function and then do the update:

```
%%[
    SET @rsContacts = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact','AccountId','Id', '=',@PersonContactId)

    IF RowCount(@rsContacts) == 0 THEN
        /* Print some sort of error message or redirect to error page */
    ELSE
        SET @accountId = Field(Row(@rsContacts,1),"AccountId")
        SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Account",@accountId,"SomeField","SomeValue")
    ENDIF
]%%
```

The back and forth between Marketing Cloud and Sales/Service Cloud is very expensive, though, and making the AccountId more available locally in Marketing Cloud would be a preferable option, as opposed to doing a RetrieveSalesforceObjects call. There are a few options:

1. Include the AccountId in your [CloudPageURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function that creates the link to your landing page and use the [RequestParameter()](http://RequestParameter) function to retrieve it.
2. Use [Send Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_email_sendlogging_de.htm&type=5) to capture the AccountId in the Send Log Data Extension and then use a [Lookup()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) function to go get it from your landing page
3. First try and get the AccountId from your Synchronised Contact_Salesforce Data Extension using a Lookup() and only when not found, resort to going directly to CRM.